# Fazer uma variavel useState global no React

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, front-end

Estou fazendo um app através do expo com react-native.Estou fazendo um botão que ao clicar quero que ele altera o `height` de um component . Eu pensei em realizar um export de uma variavel `useState` e fazer uma condição para quando clicar alterar o `styles` , porém quando eu tento transformar a variavel em `useState` em global não está funcionando , alguém sabe como?

Código Index.js :

```
import { View , TouchableOpacity ,Text , FlatList , Linking} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles'

export default function Emergencia(){
    var [aumentar, setAumentar] = useState(false);

    export {aumentar}

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}> O que fazer quando:</Text>
            <FlatList data={[1]} keyExtractor={incident => String(incident)} style={styles.list}
            renderItem={() => (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setAumentar(!aumentar)}} 
                style={styles.instructions}>
                <View>
                    <Text> Desmaio </Text>
                    <AntDesign name="caretdown" size={15} color="black" style={styles.verMais} />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            )}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Còdigo styles.js :

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import {aumentar} from './index.js'

export default StyleSheet.create({

    container : {
        backgroundColor : aumentar ? '#DF2901' : 'black',
        paddingTop : Constants.statusBarHeight + 5,
    },
    title :{
        fontSize : 30,
        color : '#13131a',
        marginTop  : 30,
        marginBottom : 16,
    }
})
```

Comment: Olá, recomendo que dê uma lida sobre a Context API do React, provavelmente é o que você deseja. Você pode encontrar informações na documentação: [Quando Usar Contexto](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se não for usar o Context ou Redux recomendo que faça a alteração do backgroundColor diretamente na folha em que se encontra o state, como por exemplo:

```
import { View , TouchableOpacity ,Text , FlatList , Linking} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles'

export default function Emergencia(){
    var [aumentar, setAumentar] = useState(false);


    return(
        <View style={{...styles.container, backgroundColor : aumentar ? '#DF2901' : 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.title}> O que fazer quando:</Text>
            <FlatList data={[1]} keyExtractor={incident => String(incident)} style={styles.list}
            renderItem={() => (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setAumentar(!aumentar)}} 
                style={styles.instructions}>
                <View>
                    <Text> Desmaio </Text>
                    <AntDesign name="caretdown" size={15} color="black" style={styles.verMais} />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            )}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

E o styles.js deverá estar como:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default StyleSheet.create({

    container : {
        paddingTop : Constants.statusBarHeight + 5,
    },
    title :{
        fontSize : 30,
        color : '#13131a',
        marginTop  : 30,
        marginBottom : 16,
    }
})
```

Espero ter ajudado.